# Automatic Scroll of Cell inside CollectionView in SWIFT

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I scroll inside a collection view such that I will always see one cell at a time,  occupying the whole screen? Like what you do when browsing individual photos in your iPhone's gallery.
Let's say:

(cell 1) |space| (cell 2)

when I scroll to the left and the space position is less than half of screen width, automatically, (cell 1) should go back to its position and occupy the screen.
But when I scroll left and space is greater than screen width, (cell 2) will automatically occupy the screen and pushing the (cell 1) away..

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you're looking for is called *paging*, but if you want a space between cells then you will need to use a custom layout (`UICollectionViewLayout` subclass) and implement 
`- targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:`. This tells the collection view where to come to a halt after the user stops interacting.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me, my God...i was searching for mathematical formulas and computation to do this manually then I learned this paging property set to true and it worked.. thank you! I hope this will help  others too